# Combine `flyspell-region` with`writegood-mode`

Tags: region, minor-mode, flyspell

I would like to combine `flyspell-region` with `writegood-mode`, but `writegood-mode` does not provide a function to check *a region* of text.

This is what I came up with to work around the limitation:

```lisp
(defun writegood-region (beginning end)
  "Check style between BEGINNING and END."
  (interactive "r")
  (narrow-to-region beginning end)
  (writegood-mode)
  (widen))

(defun prose-check-region (beginning end)
  "Check spelling and style between BEGINNING and END."
  (interactive "r")
  (when (use-region-p)
    (writegood-region beginning end)
    (flyspell-region beginning end)
    (setq deactivate-mark t)))
```

The problem is that `writegood-mode` remains enabled after the function `writegood-region` returns.

Any ideas?

Cross-posted: https://github.com/bnbeckwith/writegood-mode/issues/30

Comment: Why not just toggle `writegood-mode`after the `(widen)`?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @FranBurstall That is what I had thought would work. But, when I toggle (turn off) `writegood-mode` after `(widen)`, the highlights (fontification) is gone as well.

Comment: To expressly turn **off** a minor-mode, Emacs uses:  `(writegood-mode -1)`.  To expressly turn **on** a minor-mode on, Emacs uses `(writegood-mode 1)`.  This is generally the same for all minor-modes.

Comment: There is nothing I see in the code of `writegood-mode` that removes / deletes overlays, whether it be `flyspell` overlays or any other overlays.

Comment: @lawlist I must be missing something. When I turn `writegood-mode` on and off via `M-x`, the highlights show/hide, as expected. In my function, I would like the highlights to stay (for the region) even after the mode is turned off. `flyspell` has the same behavior, but it also provides `flyspell-region` that keeps the highlights in place.

Comment: Turning off `writegood-mode` calls `font-lock-remove-keywords` for all the keywords that were defined when that minor-mode was turned on.  So, turning off `writegood-mode` necessarily removes its highlighting.  `flyspell-region` does not use `font-lock`, it uses overlays, and said overlays are not removed automatically when `flyspell-region` finishes.  If you want `writegood-mode` higlighting to remain persistent, then that minor-mode must remain "on".  In general, `font-lock` applies to the buffer (but could be limited with some effort), whereas overlays are limited by default to a section.

Comment: @lawlist I see. Your explanation is clear and educational. Thank you! So, what I want is not easily achievable, it seems.